# Replace csv file header row with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, header

Is it possible to import a csv file into powershell, replace the entire header row with a defined set of data then save to csv file out with a new name.

I need to be able to automate this task so it can be used by another software.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be PowerShell? It is certainly possible in PowerShell but might be even easier using Excel Macros or a scripting language like Perl or Python.

Comment: No, anything that can be completely automated can work.  Just needs to be called by a scheduled task on a win 2012 server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample file contents

```powershell
1,b,4
8,j,7
8,k,9
```

To make your own header:

```powershell
Import-Csv D:\Temp\txt.txt -Header "name","letter","value"

name                                                     letter                                                   value                                                  
----                                                     ------                                                   -----                                                  
1                                                        b                                                        4                                                      
8                                                        j                                                        7                                                      
8                                                        k                                                        9
```

To skip rows:

```powershell
Import-Csv D:\Temp\txt.txt -Header "name","letter","value" | select -skip 1

name                                                     letter                                                   value                                                  
----                                                     ------                                                   -----                                                  
8                                                        j                                                        7                                                      
8                                                        k                                                        9
```

To tie it all up with an export:

```powershell
$tempCSV = Import-Csv D:\Temp\txt.txt -Header "name","letter","value" | select -skip 1
$tempCSV | Export-CSV D:\Temp\txt.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This line wont work for me     $tempCSV | Export-CSV Export-Csv C:\CSVTest\txt.txt -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I get this error  Export-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "C:\CSVTest\txt.txt" to type "System.Char". Error: 
"String must be exactly one character long."
At C:\CSVTest\Example.ps1:3 char:34
+ $tempCSV | Export-CSV Export-Csv C:\CSVTest\txt.txt -NoTypeInformation
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this can be:
    $temp = Get-Content ~\<*CSVFileName*>.csv;
    $temp[0] = $temp[0].replace($temp[0], "<*NewCommaSeperatedHeader*>");
    Set-Content -Path ~\<*ModHeaderCSVFile*>.csv -Value $temp;